# How to create SFR input for a MF6 DISV grid in Flopy?

Tags: flopy

I'm creating a MF6 disv-grid model in Flopy and want to represent a creek using the SFR package. Does anyone have experience adding SFR input to a MF6 DISV grid from a shapefile (or Shapely LineString)?

I've tried using the SFRmaker package. But unfortunately, the support for unstructured grids aren't fully implemented, and I haven't managed to find a suitable workaround.

Does anyone know of a way to create SFR input from a shapefile using Python & Flopy?